# Accessing local views' variables from .js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm stuck. I've read some blog posts about best practices on putting javascript into rails application and had a look in "Agile Web Dev With Rails3" bible — still can find no answer. So here is me begging for it.

Say I have a view (`test.erb`) which contains the following code:

```
<%@full_stack.each {|trial|%>
...
<%= button_to "test ajax", {:action => "test", :controller => "verbs", :id => @verb.id}, remote: true, :class => "check"%>
<% } %>
```

`@full_stack` is an instance variable of the respective controller. Now, I want to fetch this `trial` thing into my javascript: I'd like to compare the user's input to the string lying in the `trial` variable (the comparison is about to be made on the client-side).

This approach does not work. Putting `alert("<%= trial.class %>")` into test.js.erb leads to alert with `nil`: the javascript part can't access that variable. So, is it possible at all to access my local variables which I've created in the view from the javascript? I've seen a few similar questions here on SO but none of them is really fully explanatory.

I wouldn't be surprised to hear that my approach is totally wrong and that I should not create extra variables in the views and that such comparisons should be performed on the server side, not client side. I'm new to programming, so taking the right approach up front turns out to be difficult. Any relevant links on picking best practices when building web apps with RoR will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong there was a screencast for that stuff. You should look it on railscasts.com.